# Battery Design using Matlab Simulink

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, simulation, matlab, simulink

I am new to Simulink software and want to design a battery with 8 cells whoose voltages are 12 Volts. Their capacity is 12Ah. Both have internal resistance of 0.1 Ohms. The aim is to obtain a 24 Volts battery pack by arranging these 8 cells. The load will be 10 Ohms. In the simulink i design the following model. However, i cannot see any result on the current measurement part while i can see the 24V in the voltage measurement part. I have some several questions?
1) Even though there is no load connected to the circuitry there is this internal resistance which cause current in the branches.Why there is no indication of  current in the scope?
2) I know that there should be a ground and a resistance in the circuit. However, since they are from different librarires they are not connected. I try interfaces but nothing changes.
Anyone who have any idea about these issue please answer this question. If you want to propose another model it is also okey. Thank you for your answers in advance.[image]

Answer (score 1):

The battery's internal resistance is IN SERIES with the battery.  With no load connected, the battery will not deliver any current, and there will be no voltage dropped across the internal resistance.

With a load connected, the battery will deliver current, which will flow through the internal resistance. This current causes some voltage drop in the internal resistance, reducing the effective voltage of the [battery plus internal resistance].

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I understand it and want to ask the following. Do you know how to connect the resistor to this circuitry? They are from different libraries and i cannot connect them. What should i use to implement the resistor in this circuit?

Comment: @GiraySalgır: Sorry - I don't use Simulink, so can't help you with it.

Answer (score 0):

I think the element you were looking for is the **Series RLC Branch** in Simscape/Power Systems/Specialized Techonology/Elements, in the Simulink library. That RLC branch can be easily configured as a simple R.